# Is there a good resource which analyzes many parody movies for "what is being lampooned"?

Tags: analysis, parody

Good parody movies (e.g. Airplaine, Hot Shots) lampoon a whole bunch of things, in nearly every scene.

Is there a good resource which analyses some of the main ones scene by scene and notes a full list of what is being parodied?

Please note that I'm looking for a detailed analysis, NOT an IMDB-high-level "references these 5 movies" bullet list.

E.g. it needs to have a level of detail like this:

- "Hot shots Part Deux", in a scene where Topper Harley says "Out of all the jungles in all the countries in the world, you had to come into mine", he was lampooning a famous "Casablanca" quote "Of all the gin joints, in all the towns, in all the world, she walks into mine".

<sub>I used specifically this example because someone I know who deeply appreciates parody movies but wasn't raised on American culture was deeply shocked to find out that this was, indeed the lampooned material (since the person never saw Casablanca).</sub>

Comment: I'm shocked, shocked!, to find that parody is going on in here!

Answer (score 1):

In general most entries on IMDB will have a "Connections" link mentioning other entries that either reference or are referenced by the target. I don't believe you will ever find a complete database anywhere, but that is the one source that seems to be already trying to track this specific issue.

Sadly your example is not on the list but there are several others.

As an example see the ["Connections" page for the "Nothing but Parody" film "Epic Movie"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0799949/trivia?tab=mc)

Comment: Thank you but in the question I specifically said I was looking for `NOT an IMDB-high-level "references these 5 movies" bullet list.`

Comment: Sorry, I managed to miss that in the question. I can pull this answer since it doesn't address the request. I can't really come up with any databases that address that specific niche. Maybe it's an internet site opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Wikis such as Wikipedia and TV Tropes may be a strong possibility. Although hyperlinking isn't exactly cutting-edge technology, internal links to other pages within the same site is one of the selling points of the technology, and if it's available, they'll use it.

Sometimes Wikipedia pages even have a section dedicated to references to the work, rather than from the work.

The disadvantage with Wikipedia is that some people hate fun as much as Stack Exchange people and may regard some of this information as unencyclopedic. Still, it was very useful when I wanted to know about the Eurovision interval act "Love Love Peace Peace".